# show different statement, depends if the variable for price is empty or not

Tags: php, html, mysql

hi this is quite simple but I don't know why this does not work

so I want to show a price for a product, but some products does not have price yet, so instead of price, I want to show text like "please call our CS"

here is the code I made :

```
<?php $harga       =  number_format(($r[harga]),0,",",".");

$hargatetap= if (!empty($harga)){  
"<div class='prod_price'><span class='price'> <br /></span>&nbsp;<span class='price'>Harga Rp.$harga </span><br /></div>                        
      </div>";
      } else {
      "<div class='prod_price'><span class='price'> <br /></span>&nbsp;<span class='price'>Harga Rp.$harga </span><br /></div>                        
      <span class='price2'> <br /></span><span class='stok2'>(Hub CS) </span></div>";
      }


$divharga=$hargatetap;
 ?>
```

$divharga will be called in the other php file (I'm sure this is obvious)

Comment: `$hargatetap= if (!empty($harga)){` is a wrong syntax.

Comment: try `if($harga>0)` or whatever the number you want to compare

Comment: the problem is, the data for harga itself is empty, not 0
the are so many products so if I go around adding 0 to every one of them without price... is quite tiring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax like `$hargatetap= if (!empty($harga)){` is an invalid syntax.

Simplest solution is:

```
if (!empty($harga)) {  
    $divharga = "<div class='prod_price'><span class='price'> <br /></span>&nbsp;<span class='price'>Harga Rp.$harga </span><br /></div></div>";
} else {
    $divharga = "<div class='prod_price'><span class='price'> <br /></span>&nbsp;<span class='price'>Harga Rp.$harga </span><br /></div><span class='price2'> <br /></span><span class='stok2'>(Hub CS) </span></div>";
}

echo $divharga;
```

Comment: I forgot to delete my previous code and change with this
sorry

and thank you

Answer (score 1):

You mixed up the way an `if`statement` works in PHP. Take a look at your edited code here:

```
<?php

$harga = number_format(($r[harga]),0,",",".");
if (!empty($harga)) {
    $hargatetap = "<div class='prod_price'><span class='price'> <br /></span>&nbsp;<span class='price'>Harga Rp.$harga </span><br /></div>                        
  </div>";
} else {
    $hargatetap = "<div class='prod_price'><span class='price'> <br /></span>&nbsp;<span class='price'>Harga Rp.$harga </span><br /></div>                        
  <span class='price2'> <br /></span><span class='stok2'>(Hub CS) </span></div>";
}
$divharga=$hargatetap;
?>
```

Comment: thank you
I'm still not used to write a correct code although I know the logic, I don't know the correct syntax and semantics that's why I always come here to ask what's wrong with my code

Answer (score 1):

You should get here `Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF)`
Try

```
$hargatetap= !empty($harga) ?  
    "<div class='prod_price'><span class='price'> <br /></span>&nbsp;<span class='price'>Harga Rp.$harga </span><br /></div></div>"
    :
    "<div class='prod_price'><span class='price'> <br /></span>&nbsp;<span class='price'>Harga Rp.$harga </span><br /></div><span class='price2'> <br /></span><span class='stok2'>(Hub CS) </span></div>";
```

or

```
if (!empty($harga)){  
    $hargatetap= "<div class='prod_price'><span class='price'> <br /></span>&nbsp;<span class='price'>Harga Rp.$harga </span><br /></div></div>";
} else {
    $hargatetap= "<div class='prod_price'><span class='price'> <br /></span>&nbsp;<span class='price'>Harga Rp.$harga </span><br /></div><span class='price2'> <br /></span><span class='stok2'>(Hub CS) </span></div>";
}
```

I also noticed You have closing `</div>` without opening in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php 
 $harga       =  number_format(($r[harga]),0,",",".");
 $hargatetap= '';
 if (!empty($harga)){  
     $hargatetap .= "<div class='prod_price'><span class='price'> <br /></span>&nbsp;<span class='price'>Harga Rp.$harga </span><br /></div>                        
  </div>";
  } else {
  $hargatetap .= "<div class='prod_price'><span class='price'> <br /></span>&nbsp;<span class='price'>Harga Rp.$harga </span><br /></div>                        
  <span class='price2'> <br /></span><span class='stok2'>(Hub CS) </span></div>";
  }


$divharga=$hargatetap;
```